# Getter is not present for class setter ***

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

I developed sample Dto as follows. But it generated some errors.

```
import { Shop } from "@post-pricing/library/lib/src/orm/typeorm/entity";
import { parse } from "@post-pricing/library/lib/src/utility/date"

export class ShopTransactionsDto {
    private event;
    private shopInfo:Shop;
    private transaction;

    constructor(){
        this.event = null;
        this.shopInfo = null;
        this.transaction = null;
    }

    set setEvent(event) {
        this.event = event
    }

    get getEvent() {
        return this.event
    }

    set setShopInfo(shopInfo:Shop){
        this.shopInfo = shopInfo
    }

    get getShopInfo() {
        return this.shopInfo
    }

    set setTransaction(transaction) {
        this.transaction = transaction
    }

}
```

One of errors is follows. I set `getter` in my class. what it the root cause of this?

```
  15:5  error  Getter is not present for class setter 'setEvent'        accessor-pairs
  23:5  error  Getter is not present for class setter 'setShopInfo'     accessor-pairs
  31:5  error  Getter is not present for class setter 'setTransaction'
```

If someone has opinion,please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Your naming convention is strange. The whole point of getters and setters is to look like we're using a property: `console.log(shop.event)` and `shop.event = null` instead of `console.log(shop.getEvent())` and `shop.setEvent(null)`. With your current code, you're supposed to write `console.log(shop.getEvent)` and `shop.setEvent = null`, the worst of both world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`accessor-pairs` linter you use requires a getter and a setter to have the same name, eg:

```js
    set event(event) {
        this._event = event // note the field was renamed
    }

    get event() {
        return this._event
    }
```

References:

- https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/accessor-pairs#enforceforclassmembers

Comment: The backing field would have to be renamed so it doesn't conflict with the accessors.